# Probability of choosing M out of N Groups given that all A elements are inside M

Tags: bayesian

Assuming I have *A* number of individuals who are randomly distributed into *N* number of groups.
What is the probability of finding *A* (or any number *a* <= *A*) by picking *M* number of groups within *N*?

I figured that there are *P(M, A)* ways that the individuals can be distributed into the *M* groups. But I have no ideas how to move on from here.

Should it be conceived as:

*Pr*(Choosing *M* out of *N* | all of *A* are inside *M*)?

How should I compute the individual terms?

Comment: It's certainly not the conditional probability you mention.  You want to compute the probability that all $A$ individuals are in the $M$ groups; this is not *given*.    How exactly are individuals assigned to the groups?  "Randomly distributed" isn't very precise.  We could for example, decide on $N$ to begin with, and then assign people to the $N$ groups uniformly at random (allowing the possibility that some groups are empty, so that the original $N$ is the maximum number of groups).  Or we could assign the first person to a group, and then for each succeeding person ...

Comment: ... assign him either to one of the existing groups, or a new group, uniformly at random, or we could use some other protocol.  Where does the problem come from?